# How do I see previously installed versions of Flutter?

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I updated flutter, and it screwed everything up. There's lots of info out there on how to downgrade, but I'm not sure what I need to downgrade to.

Comment: Do you have an automated CI/CD pipeline? If so, you might be able to find the version that you need to install in the configuration file. For example, I have a `.circleci/config.yml` where I download the SDK and I have to provide it a specific version

Comment: I don't, this is a personal project.

Comment: Possible fix: do a `flutter doctor -v` that will tell you where the SDK is located. When I do this I see `Flutter version 2.8.1 at /usr/local/Caskroom/flutter/2.5.3/flutter`, which I upgraded to `2.8.1` from `2.5.3` (so if I were in your shoes, I'd downgrade to `2.5.3`), but the SDK location seems to have stayed the same. Also, if I `cd /usr/local/Caskroom/flutter`, I see the version as a directory, perhaps you'll either have the same setup I do (and the location is the old version), or you might see another directory with older versions

Comment: Also, once you know the path of your flutter SDK (its a git repo), you could also run `git reflog`, that will also tell you which branches you've changed from/to

Answer (score 0):

in your `pubspec.yaml` file, search for below line. your number might be different.

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.16.0 <3.0.0"
```

the first number is your `Dart version` when you created your project if you didn't change it. for exp my dart version is `2.16.0`.

Go to [Flutter release notes](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/sdk/release-notes) page. go to `announcement` of every flutter version and see which flutter version use your `Dart version`.